# Язык C, переполнения указателя

Tags: c, указатели, int, overflow

1) Является ли переполнение указателя переполнением **беззнакового** целого? То есть, валидно ли проверять факт переполнения после переполнения?

Например, по **Стандарту** переполнение **знакового** целого - это **UB**, из-за этого приходится проверять возможное **знаковое** переполнение до того, как оно произойдет.

2) Является ли необходимой проверка переполнения указателя?

Например, довольно часто возникает необходимость работать с данными через указатель на массив, размер элемента и количество элементов.

Например, следующая ситуация однозначно нуждается в проверке того, что умножение **size** на **count** не приведет к целочисленному переполнению типа **size_t**.

```
const void *const data = malloc(size * count);
```

Я подозреваю (но не уверен окончательно), что в проверке так же нуждается и следующая ситуация с указателем:

```
void f(const uint8_t *const _data,
       const size_t _elem_on_record,
       const size_t _records_count)
{
    const size_t record_size = sizeof(uint8_t) * _elem_on_record;
    // Контроль возможного переполнения record_size.
    // ...

    for (size_t r = 0; r < _records_count; ++r)
    {
        const size_t bias = r * record_size;
        // Контроль возможного переполнения bias.
        // ...

        const uint8_t *const select_record = _data + bias;
        // Возможно переполнение select_record, даже если
        // переполнения bias не возникло...

        f2(record);
    }
}
```

Я понимаю, что за переполнение **select_record** несет ответственность тот, кто вызвал функцию **f1**. Но я бы хотел защититься от ситуации, когда **select_record** оказывается переполнено. Это актуально для безопасности, например, сервера.

Подскажите, действительно ли нужно контролировать возможное переполнение указателя, и как это делать правильно?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84525/discussion-on-question-by---c--).

Answer (score 8):

В языке С нет и не может быть понятия "переполнения указателя". И, разумеется, никаким "целым" указатель не является.

Арифметика и упорядочивающие сравнения указателей в С определены только в пределах элементов одного массива плюс воображаемый элемент, следующий за последним элементом этого массива. Попытка создания указателя, выходящие за пределы этого диапазона ведет к неопределенному поведению (произошло ли при этот какое-то "переполнение" или нет - роли не играет). В пределах же этого диапазона, разумеется, никакого "переполнения указателя" возникнуть не может: не может существовать массива, доступ к элементам которого вызывает какое-то адресное "переполнение", ибо сам доступ к элементам массива в С концептуально реализован через адресную арифметику указателей.

Если вы работаете с массивом (блоком памяти), выделенным стандартными средствами языка, то ни о каком "переполнении указателей" вам беспокоиться не нужно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84524/discussion-on-answer-by-ant--c--).

Answer (score 0):

Указатель не является беззнаковым целым. Поддержка адресной арфиметики никак не гарантирует, что указатель есть целое. Как пример можно вспомнить адресацию в форме сегментный регистр + смещение в сегменте.

Если уж вам так непременно нужно проверять валидность адресной арифметики, используйте функции `IsBadReadPtr` и `IsBadWritePtr`.